# Canceling Insert Query - Taking Hours

Tags: sql-server-2005

I ran a query to copy 18 million records from one table to another. Since the query was taking a long time to run I was monitoring the table count to tell when it would finish.

I noticed before it reached the number it should have reached the count started dropping back down so i checked the log and it looks like sql server basically ran out of memory:

'The instance of the SQL Server Database Engine cannot obtain a LOCK resource at this time. Rerun your statement when there are fewer active users. Ask the database administrator to check the lock and memory configuration for this instance, or to check for long-running transactions.'

The actual insert only ran for about 20 minutes before the error showed up in the log.
I cancelled the query from management studio about 2 hours ago and judging by the table count this thing has only completed 25% which puts me at about 6 more hours. I'm assuming something along the lines of since all the memory is used up it is now running off the page file and that is why it is taking so long.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up? It has basically made the database unusable because everyone is getting the 'cannot obtain a lock resource' error. I could easily delete the inserted records myself, I'm wandering if perhaps I could kill the process id and 'rollback' the insert myself?

**Update**

This thing is till running remarkably slow. One thing I have found is that the # locks given by the following query seems outrageous: 83 million. The next highest is a whopping 20.

```
SELECT request_session_id, COUNT (*) num_locks
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
GROUP BY request_session_id
ORDER BY count (*) DESC
```

Comment: Well I guess it won't be able to release the locks until the transaction is finished rolling back and that it won't be aquiring new locks that could trigger a lock escalation attempt so nothing springs to mind that could free that memory. I don't think you can kill a rolling back transaction and if you were to try and restart I think it would reaquire all the original locks during database recovery so that wouldn't help either...

Comment: RE: Your edit 96 bytes per lock * 83,000,000 gives 7,968,000,000 so you are using `7.42 GB` of memory for those locks alone. How much memory is available to SQL Server on that instance? Also are you using default settings or have you altered the `locks` configuration option and/or set any of the lock related trace flags.

Comment: 32 Gigs of ram on the server, I'm not sure how much of it is allocated to SQL Server, probably whatever the default settings would be. Same goes for the locks configuration, probably default settings.

Comment: In that case I wonder if you can use the [locks configuration option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175978.aspx) to allow SQL Server to use more of that memory for the purposes of locks then? (I'm not sure about this suggestion)

Comment: We just rebooted and the database is taking a while in recovery mode - my hope is that the transaction will be rolled back while it is in recovery mode that way the memory doesn't blow up from lock usage, etc. Looking good so far...

Comment: As far as your suggestion about locks configuration, admin said the server was at 99% memory usage so, I think it was just plain out of memory.

Comment: Did that reboot work? My understanding was that SQL Server reaquires all locks during database recovery to enable [fast recovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191455.aspx) so I'd be interested to know the outcome.

Comment: The reboot did work, although it took 12 hours for the database to recover. I didn't think to re-run the query to check the number of locks, however we monitored the server memory after the reboot and the reboot definitely brought it back down to normal operation levels which enabled us to run queries in other databases that were failing before the reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to reboot the server. It did take 12 hours for the database I was working with to recover - but doing the reboot cleared up the resource issues we were having with applications accessing the other databases. The next time I tried this I broke it down into batches of 500K instead of all 18 million at once and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the thing cancelled, you need to fix your code to do the insert. First, if you are working one record at a time in a cursor (and all in the same transaction) that will take forever to run. If you used a set-based insert, you can have the issue you describe as well. If you can do this using bulk insert that can work nicely or what you do is a combination of the row-by-row and set-based approach which is to run batches of records in a loop. (I usually start with 2000 at a time and if that is fast move it to more records.) Just make sure to test that you are not trying to insert the same batch of records repeatedly.

Comment: thanks, i love and use bulk inserts all the time, in this scenarior it was not possible

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that rebooting is required. Restart `SQL Server Service` is enough for the same. I will recommend to restart the `SQL server service`. And It would solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Disconnect all other users processes.  You may even have to change the database to "admin only" to prevent other connections.  Make sure you have no other processing running that are blocking your original update statement.

This will hopefully free up some memory and/or prevent other processes from using what little memory is available.

This command will flush out the cache, which may possible help by removing all cached data from memory.  Hopefully this will remove data that was used by the other processes and make more room for your current query.

dbcc dropcleanbuffers

Comment: DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS will not change the amount of time that a rollback requires.

Comment: I never said it would.  I was just hoping to free up as much memory as possible for the current main process to use.